# How i set the div height from next img tag?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello friends i'm new on stack. I'll wait for your helps. , i have a problem with my project. I want to set my `.game-tags-main` div height same as the img next to it.

**Img height is responsive so i Want div height to be responsive as well**. 
But I donot want to use javaScript in this project.
Below are the code snippets of my project.

---

HTML

```
<div class="games-box">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="game-tags-main">
                asd
            </div>
            <img src="img/games/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="head-of-games">
            <h3>Hounds Online</h3>
            <span class="button-radius">İNDİRİMDE</span>
        </div>
        <p>Grim Dawn</p>
        <div class="price">
            <span class="game-discount">325,00 ₺</span>
            <span>245,00 ₺</span>
        </div>
        <div class="add-basket">
            <a href="#" class="button-red button-radius">SEPETE EKLE</a>
            <a href="#" class="button-grey button-radius">İNCELE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
.games-box {
    > div {
        width:18.8%;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 0.6% 30px 0.6%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
        padding-bottom:20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -o-border-radius: 3px;
        overflow:hidden;
        .game-tags-main {
            height: calc(100%);
            background:red;
        }
        img {
            width:102%;
            margin-left:-1%
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by 'set my .game-tags-main div height from the next img' ? Do you need set the same height as the image ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) CSS reference.

Comment: Hello sir, <img src="img/games/1.jpg" alt=""> this img size will be changes from browser size, it's a responsive one. I want the set ".game-tags-main" this class height like a img. But img size dynamic.

Comment: Thank you senal, but it's don't about the selectors. It's about calc the img height dynamicly and set this dynamic height to my div.

Comment: With js it's a very easy. Can i make this with just css codes ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you have `.games-box > div`? This is not correct according to the rules of css. I saw that you nested the `img` inside the `games-box` class. Your tag says that you are supposed to be using `flexbox`, but there is no property in the CSS where you're saying `display: flex;`. You asked the question "I want the set my .game-tags-main div height from the next img". You aren't adding your styles to the `game-tags-main` `div class`.

The `border-radius` property is unnecessary to be used so many times. If a browser isn't compatible, the curve just won't show up. All in all, please restate this question as it is, currently, very confusing.

Comment: If i put all the lines of code here, it would be very confusing. This is the simplest way. I catch the div with > this selector because back ender wants this. I'll will be upload to codepen. thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.games-box > div > div {
    position: relative;
}
.games-box > div .game-tags-main {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
if you want .game-tags-main is full width just add Width="100%"....
```